# Returning values from a function : reference vs struct

Tags: c++, struct, parameter-passing, return-value

I'm new to programming and I'm studying the C++ programming language using the book : Programming principles and practice using C++. I'm here today because at the end of chapter 8, the author focuses on functions and proposes an exercise to invite the learner to think about the better solution to a problem :

> Write a function that finds the smallest and the largest element of a vector argument and also computes the mean and the median. Do not use global variables. Either return a `struct` containing the results or pass them back through reference arguments. Which of the two was of returning several values do you prefer and why ?

Now, usually I wouldn't define a single function to perform several actions but in this case I have to create just one function and think about how to return several values. My first approach was to create a function that takes reference arguments like this :

```
void my_func(
    vector<double>& numbers,
    double& min,
    double& max,
    double& mean,
    double& median
);
```

But going on with writing the program I started to think that this solution used too many arguments and maybe the other solution proposed (using `struct`) would be better. How would you use a `struct` to solve this problem ? How do you return several values from a function ?

Comment: You don't return several values from a function, that's impossible. Instead you return *one* structure instance, containing several members (for example members like `min`, `max` etc.).

Comment: Use [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) whenever it's useful and possible. Here it is possible and useful and therefore you should use a struct here (e.g. stats) as proposed in the answers.

Comment: If you're using c++11, you might want to take a look at [std::tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)

Answer (score 5):

Using `struct` for this problem is simple: define a `struct` for the return type, and use it, like this:

```
struct stats {
    double min;
    double max;
    double mean;
    double median;
};
stats my_func(vector<double>& numbers) {
    stats res;
    ...
    res.min = ...
    res.max = ...
    res.mean = ...
    res.median = ...
    return res;
}
```

The tradeoff here is that in exchange for having a much simpler function signature, the users of your function need to extract the elements that they want one by one.

> But what about if the struct is really complex and the cost of copying becomes too expensive?

It takes a structure of extreme size for copying to become too expensive in comparison to the "payload" CPU time of your function. On top of that, C++ optimizer reduces the copying costs by employing [*copy elision*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) and [return value optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) strategies when you do this:

```
stats s = my_func(numbers);
```

When the `struct` becomes so gigantic that you don't want to copy it, combine the two approaches like this:

```
void my_func(vector<double>& numbers, stats& res);
```

Comment: @PoojaNilangekar Thanks, it was a good edit. Unfortunately, it got rejected automatically because I was in the process of editing the answer myself. Thank you for catching this copy-paste error!

Comment: From the basics thing I've learned I know when the function returns a value in your example a copy of return_value is created. But what about if the struct is really complex and the cost of copying becomes too expensive ?

Comment: @pieroborrelli With move semantics and copy elision chances are good you won't actually make a copy. Especially if you initialize a variable from the function return.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the `struct`

i.e.

```
struct stats {
   double min;
   double max;
   double mean;
   double median;
};
```

Then

```
stats my_func(vector<double>& numbers);
```

The function will be like this

```
stats my_func(vector<double>& numbers) {
    stats return_value;

     // Fill in the structure

    return return_value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you just return a struct.

```
struct res {
   double min; 
   double max;
   double mean;
   double median;
};

res my_func(vector<double>& numbers) {
    res result;
    // do stuff, put result in in result.min etc

    return result;
}
```

The other can be done in a similar way:

```
void my_func(vector<double>& numbers,
             res& result)
{
    // the same code except no return value

    return;
}
```

Now for the question in your task (which I shall not answer - because it's a question what you prefer) I'd like to mention what the technical difference is.

When returning a struct it means you will possibly create a temporary copy of the `result` struct (it may also result in two objects `res` one for the caller and one for `my_func` to work with). While the other approach means that you pass to the function essentially addresses where to put the result. With a "good" implementation you may end up with the same code.

Comment: With move semantics and copy elision chances are good you won't actually make a copy.  Especially if you initialize a variable from the function return.

Comment: The probability for that has changed, I changed it form "probably" to "possibly" to indicate that it's less probable these days.